# append and remove on slide up / down when click radio btn in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button, append, slider

I want to create when I click <kbd>Radio2</kbd> >> inside that div will append and current <kbd>Radio2</kbd> will removed again when I click <kbd>Radio1</kbd> >> inside that div of <kbd>Radio1</kbd> will be append and <kbd>Radio1</kbd> will remove and <kbd>Radio2</kbd> container will removed and <kbd>Radio2</kbd> will append.
I can manage this by hide and show but I could archive that.
I want to make that similar append function please anybody know Please help me out by append function else button hide and show function. Append function will really helpful for me and it will very appreciated.

PLEASE HELP ME.

```js
(function(d) {
  "use strict";
  var blockParent = $(".input-block");
  var myAccordion = $(".form-row");
  blockParent.removeClass("active");
  myAccordion.hide();
  $(".input-block:first").addClass("active");
  $('.form-first').slideDown();
  $(".ac-container").on("click", ".label-toggle", function() {
    if (!$(this)
      .next()
      .is(":visible")
    ) {
      myAccordion.slideUp();
      blockParent.removeClass("active");
      $(this)
        .closest(".input-block")
        .addClass("active");
      $(this)
        .next()
        .slideDown("slow", function() {});
    }
  });
})(document);
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}

form {
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.ac-container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  .ac-container {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
}

.form-row {
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

.form-row p {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

.label-toggle {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.active .label-toggle {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: default;
}

.active .label-toggle span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.label-last {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.label-toggle:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.active .label-toggle:before {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background: orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 127, 80, 0.8);
}

.label-toggle:focus:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 4px rgba(255, 127, 80, 0.8);
}

.label-toggle:hover:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 127, 80, 0.8);
}

.label-toggle span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.label-toggle small {
  font-weight: normal;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Login Form</h1>
<div class="ac-container">

  <div class="input-block active">
    <button type="button" class="label-toggle"><span>Radio1</span></button>
    <div class="form-row form-first">
      This is first DIV
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-block active">
    <button type="button" class="label-toggle"> <span>Radio 2 <small>(Smaller text)</small></span></button>
    <div class="form-row">
      This is second DIV
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-block active">
    <button type="button" class="label-toggle"> <span>Radio 3 <small>(Smaller text)</small></span></button>
    <div class="form-row">
      This is third DIV
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```